# remove empty rows from array

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

I want to remove empty rows from array in `php`, I used `array_filter` that gives perfect result. 
Here is my code which I have tried

```
$cars = array
  (
  array("Volvo",22,18),
  array("BMW",15,13),
  array("Saab",5,2),
  array("",'','')
  );

  $cars= array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $cars));

  echo "<pre>"; print_r($cars);

the output is following for above array is :-

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Volvo
            [1] => 22
            [2] => 18
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => BMW
            [1] => 15
            [2] => 13
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Saab
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 2
        )

)
```

the output is perfect as it removed the empty rows, but when I create new array like below

```
$cars = array
  (
  array("Volvo",22,18),
  array("BMW",15,13),
  array("Saab",5,2),
  array("",54,'')
  );
```

in last array it remove the first and last column and keep it remain the 1 position column in the array. like below:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Volvo
        [1] => 22
        [2] => 18
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => BMW
        [1] => 15
        [2] => 13
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Saab
        [1] => 5
        [2] => 2
    )

    [3] => Array
    (
        [1] => 54
    )

)
```

I only want to remove empty row not the column so array return should be like below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Volvo
            [1] => 22
            [2] => 18
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => BMW
            [1] => 15
            [2] => 13
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Saab
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => ''
            [1] => 54
            [2] => ''
        )

)
```

Comment: You can define a custom callback for `array_filter` and set what you want to filter in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
$cars = array
(
    array("Volvo",22,18),
    array("BMW",15,13),
    array("Saab",5,2),
    array("",'','')
);

// Here we `implode` all values of current subarray 
// and if this imploded string is empty - skip subarray
$cars = array_filter($cars, function($v) { return implode('', $v) !== ''; });
echo '<pre>', print_r($cars), '</pre>';
```

Comment: one query related to this if i have large array data set , like 2000 rows in an array , will this solution take too time?

Comment: You should try, but i suppose it will be faster than `array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $cars))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use loop for filter multidimensional array

```
$valueArray = array();
foreach ( $cars as $value ) {
    $valueArray[] = array_filter($value);
}
echo '<pre>'; print_r($valueArray);
```

Comment: one query related to this if i have large array data set , like 2000 rows in an array , will foreach  create issue?, like too much time to execute and respond

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for a **nested array**, this will also work for normal arrays. This will delete every **"" value** and **empty arrays** you can also add your own rules.

```
static function unsetEmptyRows($array)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            if (empty($value)) {
                unset($array[$key]);
            } else {
                $array[$key] = self::unsetEmptyRows($value);
                foreach ($array as $i => $a) {
                    if (empty($a)) {
                        unset($array[$i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            if ($value == "") {
                unset($array[$key]);
            }
            // You can add own rules here
        }
    }

    return $array;
}
```